# ReactJs update parent after ComponentDidMount from child class

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent class and a child class. The child class will perform an initial load operation based on a property passed from the parent. The parent class will access that data using a static method from the child. In essence, I'm trying to use the child class as a service. The code below illustrates the scenario (note that it's just pseudo code).

```
var Parent = React.createClass({

 componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log("parent component was mounted");
 },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child param={this.props.param} />
        <p>Child.fetch('key')</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: {}
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        console.log("child component was mounted");

        $.ajax({
          url: "server/api.php",
        data: {
         param: param
        }
        }).done(function(response) {
          this.setState({data: response});
        }.bind(this));
    },

    statics: {
        get: function(key) {
            console.log('get requested for key: ' + key);

            var value = null; // default value

            if(this.data == null) { return value; }

            //get the value from the data based on the key

            return value;
        }
    },        

  render: function() {
    return (
      <h2>{this.props.param}</h2>
    );
  }
});
```

The problem here is that the parent's render function does not update after the data was loaded from the child class. The order of the console.log results is:

1. Parent render: get requested for key: key
2. parent component was mounted
3. child component was mounted
4. => should trigger an update to re-render the parent

I'm not sure if its possible to trigger the parent's render function only once after the child component has been loaded. I'm guessing its not, so triggering an update for the parent's render method would suffice. Any suggestions, improvements are welcome as this is fairly new to me.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. If the child component is not rendering based on the response, why are you doing this in the child component rather than in the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a callback prop to your `Child` component that the child can trigger once the data has been loaded.

On the `Parent` side you just need to call `this.forceUpdate()`.

What you are experiencing is expected since the lifecycle of your `Child` component is different than the one for your `Parent` class.

Still, you might need to analyze the possibility to move your load logic into the `Parent` and delegate the rendering of parts of the response to each child. This will also help performance since only one HTTP request will be needed to load all the data.

** Code **

```
var Parent = React.createClass({

 componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log("parent component was mounted");
 },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child param={this.props.param} onDataLoaded={this.forceUpdate} />
        <p>Child.fetch('key')</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: {}
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        console.log("child component was mounted");

        $.ajax({
          url: "server/api.php",
        data: {
         param: param
        }
        }).done(function(response) {
          if (typeof this.onDataLoaded === 'function')
            this.onDataLoaded();
          this.setState({data: response});
        }.bind(this));
    },

    statics: {
        get: function(key) {
            console.log('get requested for key: ' + key);

            var value = null; // default value

            if(this.data == null) { return value; }

            //get the value from the data based on the key

            return value;
        }
    },        

  render: function() {
    return (
      <h2>{this.props.param}</h2>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: The thing is I want to have a re-usable kind of service that I can easily plug in to any class without adding the same load logic over and over again. I understand your suggestion, but could you provide a (pseudo) code example as well to illustrate it?

Comment: Particularly the `onDataLoaded` prop in the render function of the `Parent` and the call in the `done` callback of your ajax response.

Comment: I just added `if (typeof this.onDataLoaded === 'function')` so you can still use the `Child` in parents that don't want to be notified of the changes.

Comment: This should work just fine thanks, I'm still looking into loading from the parent class in a re-usable way to avoid an additional update.